# PuTTy Fatal Error while trying to connect to Raspberry Pi 3B+ via SSH: “Network error: Connection timed out”

Tags: ssh, putty, raspberry-pi, ip-address

PuTTy: I get the Error you see in the title while trying to connect to my raspberry pi 3B+ via SSH from windows.

I tried to ping it but I get this:

```
Pinging 192.168.178.201 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.178.87: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.178.87: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.178.87: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.178.87: Destination host unreachable.
```

The IP adresse I pinged is the one from the raspberry pi, it's already a static one. I did it like it's described [here](https://blog.buettner.xyz/raspberry-pi-raspbian-jessie-lite-raspbian-stretch-lite-statische-ip-adresse/). It's not within the dhcp range of my router (20 to 200).

The raspberry pi is otherwise working just fine. I also enabled SSH on the pi itself, this shouldn't be the problem either. I honestly don't know what's wrong.

I also set the "seconds between keepalives" in putty to 10, didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping from the raspberry to your machine? If not, verify that the IP address is correctly asigned in the pi, that the mask is the same and both machines are using the same gateway.

Comment: Checked it, ip adress, mask, gateway is all ok. I even did [this](https://www.instructables.com/Direct-Network-Connection-between-Windows-PC-and-R/) method. Now I can ping the pi from the laptop and visa versa. But connection via putty still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok now that you have connection check the firewall in the pi, make sure that it is accepting ssh connections, port 22, and check that you have the ssh service up and running in the pi

Comment: I now enabled SSH Access in the firewall following [this](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/iptables-add-rule/) tutorial but it still doesn't work...

Comment: What operating system are you using in that pi?